# Replace words in sentence

Tags: c

I am trying to make a function in C where the function has to replace given word with another given word in sentence. This is my code but it does not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void repl(char* sentence, char* thiss, char* change_to_this) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    int length_thiss = strlen(thiss);
    int length_change_to_this = strlen(change_to_this);

    while (sentence[i] != 0) {

        if (sentence[i] == this[j]) {

            int init = i;

            while (sentence[init] == thiss[j] && thiss[j] != 0)
            {
                j++;
                init++;
            }
            if (thiss[j] == 0) {
                j -= length_thiss;

                for (int m = 0; m < length_thiss; m++) {

                    sentence[i] = change_to_this[m];
                }
                j = 0;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This should be result:

```
char sent[] = "My name is John and I am thirty years old.";
char name1[] = "John";
char name2[] = "Rick";
char age1[] = "thirty";
char age2[] = "fifty";
replace(sent, name1, name2);
replace(sent, age1, age2);
printf("result: %s\n", a); // My name is Rick and I am fifty years old.
```

Length of `thiss` is at least the same as the length of `change_to_this`. I cannot include any other libraries except those 2 I already included. Any ideas how to correct the code, please?

Comment: You should treat `sent` as immutable. Don't manipulate a fixed-length string buffer like that. Clone it first.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a detailed enough diagnostic. Can you better describe what it is you're trying to achieve, what output you're getting, if any, with particular attention paid to *any* errors generated by this code? What is this code supposed to do? It's very important to be as specific as you can, and this may require doing some additional investigation as to the root cause of your problem before posting a question.

Comment: Well you do not reset `j` only in an `if` condition so that could be a problem.

Comment: This one cant work at all yo need to move the rest of the string depending of length of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

if you use string functions it can be archived much easier

```
char *repl(char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *repl)
{
    size_t hLen = strlen(haystack), nLen = strlen(needle), rLen = strlen(repl);
    char *pos, *nhs = haystack;

    
    while((pos = strstr(nhs, needle)))
    {
        memmove(pos + rLen, pos + nLen, hLen - (pos - haystack) - nLen + 1);
        memcpy(pos, repl, rLen);
        nhs = pos + rLen;
    }
    return haystack;
}

int main()
{
    char sent[] = "My name is Johnatan and I am thirty years old.";
    char name1[] = "Johnatan";
    char name2[] = "Rich";
    char age1[] = "thirty";
    char age2[] = "fifty five";
    repl(sent, name1, name2);
    printf("result: %s\n", sent); // My name is Rick and I am fifty years old. 
    repl(sent, age1, age2);
    printf("result: %s\n", sent); // My name is Rick and I am fifty years old. 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/2fK3XY

In my another answers you will find all the functions used written by hand

## EDIT

As in the deleted comment - amended to replace all occurrences.

the caller is responsible for the size of the haystack.

Comment: I like where you are going, but you run into problems if in your example you replace `"johnatan"` with `"Sylvester"`, etc... (e.g. the sum of replacements size exceeds sum of the needles and that isn't available..) A quick check of the space available would be needed which would require passing `size_t haystack_size` as a parameter. At least warrants a good note in the answer.